# Subquery result in the WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to run a sql like this:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM ExpandQa WHERE ExpandQa.questionId = id) AS qaCount
FROM Question
WHERE (actId = 9)
  AND (flowState = 40)
  AND (((type = 0
     AND qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND 29)
     OR (type <> 0
     AND qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND 19)))
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

The result is --> invalid column name 'qaCount'。
My db is SQL Server.

I can fix the problem like this

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM ExpandQa WHERE ExpandQa.questionId = id) AS qaCount
FROM Question
WHERE (actId = 9)
  AND (flowState = 40)
  AND (((type = 0
     AND (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM ExpandQa WHERE ExpandQa.questionId = id) BETWEEN 1 AND 29)
     OR (type <> 0
     AND (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM ExpandQa WHERE ExpandQa.questionId = id) BETWEEN 1 AND 19)))
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

But I'm afraid that it will be slower.
"qaCount" is used three times. I don't hope "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ExpandQa WHERE ExpandQa.questionId=id)" is written three times.

Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to put every boolean expression in the `WHERE` in parathesis (`()`). The only time you really need them around boolean expressions is when  dealing with `OR` logic.

Comment: Can you add some sample data? Looks like that you can handle this by joining to `ExpandQa`

Comment: How it could be slower than a query that doesn't work? I agree that getting the same aggregate repeatedly is less than ideal. You could drop the main query into a cte but I agree with the previous comment that this could likely be rewritten with a join instead of a subquery.

Comment: Is it intended that in the second query both have `type = 0`?

Comment: And not one we can answer as we can't run the query, nor have *any* of the indexes on their table(s); hence why the OP is in a far better position that us to test and *run their horses* @SQLpro .

Comment: @Larnu I made a typo. It's ..... (type=0 AND ...) OR (type<>0 and ...)

Comment: `SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ExpandQa WHERE ExpandQa.questionId=id) as qaCount  AS qaCount ..` are you sure? It should throw a syntax error.

Comment: @Serg Sorry, I change again

Comment: Dear OP, you should write answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way to introduce computed data is a lateral join (APPLY)

```
SELECT *, cnt.qaCount
FROM Question q
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS qaCount
  FROM ExpandQa e
  WHERE e.questionId = q.id
) cnt
WHERE (actId = 9)
  AND (flowState = 40)
  AND (((type = 0
     AND cnt.qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND 29)
     OR (type <> 0
     AND cnt.qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND 19)))
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify as :

```
WITH
T AS
(
SELECT *, COUNT(ExpandQa.questionId) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS qaCount
FROM   Question
)
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE  actId = 9
  AND flowState = 40
  AND (   (type =  0 AND qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND 29)
       OR (type <> 0 AND qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND 19))
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Also, this predicate

```
AND (   (type =  0 AND qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND 29)
       OR (type <> 0 AND qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND 19))
```

can be optimized with :

```
AND qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND CASE type WHEN 0 THEN 29 ELSE 19 END
```

Comment: Honestly, this doesn't need the `OR`. It might as well be `AND type = 0 AND qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND 29`. If that statement is true, then so too is `type = 0 AND qaCount BETWEEN 1 AND 19`. It would be like having `WHERE Column BETWEEN 1 AND 10 OR Column BETWEEN 4 AND 6`.

Comment: @Larnu - the OP changed that predicate themselves between their first and second query. The top one in the question has <> on the predicate with 19.

Comment: I know that, @SeanLange , I've already [questioned it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73556399/subquery-result-in-the-where-clause/73556513?noredirect=1#comment129893695_73556399), but if the above is a simplification, then it should either simplyfy it (by omitting the latter clause), or address the (likely) typographical error.

Comment: @Larnu agreed that if this is correct it could be simplified by removing the extra predicate.

Comment: I run that SQL but fail. Then I change a little, It's successful. I'll write it at my question.